# Concat Children Nodes XPathEntityProcessor Solr DIH

Tags: xpath, solr, transformer-model, dih

I am trying to make a solr field's value contain information about a parent child relationship in the XML via DIH.

Here is the dataConfig:

```
<dataConfig>
   <script>
      <![CDATA[
         function doSomething(row){
             //logic
             return row;
         }
      ]]>
   </script>
   <dataSource type="URLDataSource"/>
    <document>
         <entity name="getModels"
            pk="id"
            url="pathpathpath"
            processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
            forEach="/path"
            transformer="script:doSomething"
            >
                <field column="spec" xpath="/Group/name/SubGroup" transformer="script:doSomething"/> 
                <field column = ... />
          </entity>
    </document>
```

Sample XML:

```
<Group>
   <name>
      Vehicle
   </name>
   <SubGroup>
        <name>Car</name>
   </SubGroup>
   <SubGroup>
        <name>Bike</name>
   </SubGroup>
</Group>

<Group>
   <name>
      Fruit
   </name>
   <SubGroup>
        <name>Apple</name>
   </SubGroup>
   <SubGroup>
        <name>Banana</name>
   </SubGroup>
</Group>
```

How would I specify in:

```
 <field column="spec" xpath="/Group/name/SubGroup" transformer="script:doSomething"/>
```

So that I can have the corresponding instances of spec be:

```
Vehicle Car
```

and

```
Vehicle Bike
```

and

```
Fruit Apple
```

and

```
Fruit Banana
```

Ideally with a delimiter between name and subname like:

```
Fruit::Banana
```

Comment: If the you store "Fruit" and "Banana" already in two fields you can create a new field value for the `spec` column from those field values using the TemplateTransformer: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-TheTemplateTransformer

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a better approach.

We can use an XSL translation on the input xml to do any necessary formatting beforehand.

In this case, the xsl transforms the xml to be solr index ready e.g:

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">MyID</field>
    .....
  </doc>
  ...

</add>
```

Here is the data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>

  <dataSource type="URLDataSource"/>
       <document>
         <entity name="getModels"
            pk="id"
            stream="true"
            url="pathpathpath"
            processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
            xsl="path"
            forEach="/doc"
            useSolrAddSchema="true"
         >
               <field column="id" xpath="/add/doc/field[@name='id']"/>
               ...
       </entity>

     </document>

</dataConfig>
```

This was a workaround rather than a direct solution.  But I hope this helps if anyone else is going through this.  There is a paucity of custom DIH documentation online, and have had much trouble getting this accomplished.